# Inserting latex lines into a pdf?

Tags: pdf

Apologies in advance if this is a simple question. I spent a couple hours on google and couldn't really figure it out! 
I takes Physics notes at uni by editing PDFs that contain skeleton notes. I recently figured out how to use an add-on for Microsoft Word called MathType, which me gives a menu tab that I can select to enter a line of Latex formulas.
I am wondering if there is something similar to this that I can use with a PDF editing program (such as Adobe Acrobat, Skim, etc.)?
Essentially, how can I edit PDFs that do not already contain any Latex formulas?

Comment: even with acrobat pdf only allows extremely limited editing capabilities, it s really a "final rendered" document format not an editable one, what kind of edits do you need to make, if you insert text/formulae etc existing text will not usually reflow over pages etc?

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! There is `.pdf` editing software, but I don't know of a `LaTeX` - ready one. Best you could get (I suppose) is to insert the formulas as sub-pdfs and generate the formulas directly with LaTeX and then generate the sub-pdf, but this is tedious, probably

Comment: This _sounds_ off-topic to me.

Comment: I don't understand how you are editing the PDFs which contain the 'skeleton notes'. As others have said, editing text is usually problematic - even with the most whizzy version of Acrobat.

Comment: @Werner: I agree... as the LaTeX - content is not clear at all

Comment: If there is sufficient space in the PDF you _can_ use LaTeX to overwrite with other text (including formulas).  This is going to be a bid tedious, but if your desire is to have one PDF that has your LaTeX typeset formulas and the skeleton notes, this would certainly work.  If this may be useful to you  please provide a sample .pdf page which and the LaTeX code of formulas you wish to have in it.